# Kibana docker run

Tags: docker, kibana

I create a container with ubuntu's image.

That's all right, and i can use very well.

So, i install kibana service in this ubuntu's docker.

When i execute the kibana on path bin , run correct and say that is listening on : localhost:5601

It means the kibana is configured correct, but when i access on my browser out of docker , doesn't work.

I have already configured the network on kibana.yml file in the correct path.

i can see the service running on docker(cmd).

My initial kibana.yml file:

```
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
#server.port: 5601

# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are both valid values.
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
# server.host: "0.0.0.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each container has its own localhost, which is not accessible from outside.

Your question contains the answer:

```
# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are both valid values.
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
# server.host: "0.0.0.0"
```

Uncomment the last line of that block to run the server on the "external" interface of the container. Then it will be accessible from outside.

That will allow other containers to reach it. If you want to bind the port so non-containers can access it, run the container with the `-p` flag to publish the port.

```
docker run -p 5601:5601 [.....]
```

Comment: Work, i try this before but i don't know why doesn't work , but thank you !